# Flink SQL Windows not Reporting Final Results

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm using Flink SQL to compute event-time-based windowed analytics. Everything works fine until my data source becomes idle each evening, after which the results for the last minute aren't produced until the next day when data begins to flow again.

```sql
CREATE TABLE input
    id STRING,
    data BIGINT,
    rowtime TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp',
    WATERMARK FOR rowtime AS rowtime - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'input',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
    'format' = 'json'
)

SELECT ...
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
     TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE input, DESCRIPTOR(rowtime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES)))
GROUP BY ..., window_start, window_end
```

I've tried setting `table.exec.source.idle-timeout`, but it didn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`table.exec.source.idle-timeout` (and the corresponding `withIdleness` construct used with the DataStream API for WatermarkStrategy) detects idle input partitions and prevents them from holding back the progress of the overall watermark. However, for the overall watermark to advance, there must still be some input, somewhere.

Some options:

(1) Live with the problem, which means waiting until the watermark can advance normally, based on observing larger timestamps in the input stream. As you've indicated, in your use case this can require waiting several hours.

(2) Arrange for the input stream(s) to contain keep-alive messages. This way the watermark generator will have evidence (based on the timestamps in the keep-alive messages) that it can advance the watermark. You'll have to modify your queries to ignore these otherwise extraneous events.

(3) Upon reaching the point where the job has fully ingested all of the daily input, but hasn't yet produced the final set of results, [stop the job](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/cli/#terminating-a-job) and specify `--drain`. This will send a watermark with value MAX_WATERMARK through the pipeline, which will close all pending windows. You can then restart the job.

(4) Implement a custom watermark strategy that uses a processing-time timer to detect idleness and artificially advance the watermark based on the passage of wall clock time. This will require converting your table input to a DataStream, adding the watermarks there, and then converting back to a table for the windowing. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/ for examples of these conversions.

Comment: Hi David, please elaborate regarding the 4th solution. 
Our case: Flink 1.17.1, Kafka sources, table=>datastream conversion (possibly union of streams), datastream=>table and sink. Event-time timestamps. 
With table-only streams, `table.exec.source.idle-timeout` + `.watermark("timestamp", "`timestamp` - INTERVAL '3' second")` do the trick.
But it's messed up once mixing table and datastreams, despite using `withIdleness` with BoundedOutOfOrderness.
The doc seems silent about dealing with idleness when combining table and datastreams, while this can be a show-stopper in real-life use-cases.

Comment: Please elaborate on "messed up".

Comment: I meant the watermark progression is blocked. According to the watermark value shown by the Flink UI, for some reason, the timestamp of the watermark jumps to `9223372036854776000` (near Long.MAX_VALUE)...